# Mysql like operator

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates. Station consists of a column called city.

Query:

```
SELECT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[AEIOU]%[AEIOU]';
```

How is this wrong? It produces no output.

Comment: Take a look at REGEXP.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html).

Your code should be like

```
SELECT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEIOU].*[AEIOU]$';
```

Comment: What does the . (dot) do? Does it break the starting type style?

Comment: .* mean zero or more character. It could be any number of character. ".*" is regular expression convention.

Comment: Thanks, so you referred the mysql documentation right?

Comment: I gave you refernce to mysql documentation. I know regex very well.